# Page redirect based on referrer

Tags: rules, http-request

I am looking for an option to redirect user referred from a specific url (say abc.com) to domain.com/abc in Drupal 7
if http_referrer='abc.com' redirect to xyz.com/abc 
I looked at Redirect, http response headers modules but need something for http_referrer.

Preferably without code modification.

Comment: Is it required to do this in code or can you use nginx/apache configuration to handle everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a redirect in the .htaccess file if you're using Apache. Something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*abc.com  [NC]
  RewriteRule .* http://example.com/abc  [R] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @ponies. I should have been more specific, I have to do it without htaccess modification.

Comment: @Sandeep Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Shai I couldnt find a solution within Drupal but implemented thru javascript code.